# RETURN all paths from root to leaf in n-ary tree

Tags: python

There's a lot out there about how to *print* all paths from root to leaf in a tree, but I'm trying to *return* them. Each node has a list of children, and I need to return a list of strings where each string represents a path. I.e with the tree

```
   A
  /\
  B F
/ | \
C D  E
```

I should return ['A, B, C', 'A,B,D', 'A,B,E', 'A,F']
The function must be recursive and done in python. I've tried this function for a while, but am getting stuck wrapping my head around the recursion. I.e if my function starts with path="", then every time I recall the function I lose that path...

*Edit: solved with help from @flakes's answer and modifying `yield [root.value] + path` to `yield [root.value+", "+path[0])`

Comment: Please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: can you show us the definition of the tree in your script ?

Comment: It's important that you provide what you tried until now. This forum is not suitable for solving problems for you, rather we can help you with specific issues you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Start by defining a class for your node structure. It should have a value, and a list of child nodes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children or []
```

For returning data from recursive functions, I like to use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) as they can simplify the logic a lot.

The first use case is when there are no children. The result should be `[value]`.

When there are children, you want to loop each child in the children list, find their respective paths, and for each path, append the current `[value]` to their result.

You might get something like this:

```
def find_paths(root):
    if len(root.children) == 0:
        yield [root.value]

    for child in root.children:
        for path in find_paths(child):
            yield [root.value] + path
```

Test case:

```
tree = Node('a', [Node('b', [Node('c'), Node('d'), Node('e')]), Node('f')])

for path in find_paths(tree):
    print(path)
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'e']
['a', 'f']
```

---

If you need it as one flat list, then I would just flatten the result after the call:

```
output = [value for path in find_paths(tree) for value in path]
```

Comment: You must import dataclass from dataclasses

Comment: @AminGuermazi Ya know, I'll take out the typehints and dataclass to keep it simpler

Comment: @flakes Thanks! But I need to return all the paths in one long list

Comment: @JacobMitrani `list(find_paths(tree))`

Comment: @flakes Thanks so much for this- but I need the output to be ['a, b, c', 'a, b, d'...], i.e each path as one string where nodes are separated by comma.

Comment: @JacobMitrani see the last comment, you can flatten the lists: `[value for path in find_paths(tree) for value in path]`